# Dual-Homed EC2 Instance

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

I've been doing a bit of deep-diving into AWS for hosting a project I am working on, so far from what I can see it has everything I could want for, except for one thing.

I've been trying to launch an instance that has a leg in two different logical networks. One leg in network A (10.32.0.0/22) and one leg in network B (240.251.0.0/16), from what I can tell this isn't possible and that instances can only be seated in a single VPC.

Is this right or am I completely missing something?

Comment: This is right, but what are you trying to accomplish?  Assuming there's a need for this at all -- the peculiarities of VPCs and peering may make it unnecessary or the peculiarities of VPC may prevent what you think this would accomplish, even if it were possible -- there may be a good solution or workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create another elastic network interface inside the same VPC.

Can you give us more of a big picture on what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to give you another way to address your issue.